# Why does Tomcat 'Out of Memory' right when I attempt to start server in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, maven

As soon I click to start (literally immediately) the tomcat server with my web app, it displays the following error:
http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h282/jamesekki/error.jpg

What's weird is the application still builds successfully and works fine. The problem is it slows down development time since I get this error every time I need to deploy any changes.

Here is my eclipse ini:
http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h282/jamesekki/Capture.jpg

Any ideas?

Things I have tried:
1. Increased xms/xmx in increments of 128 megs all the way up to 4 gigs (still fail)
2. Increased permsize/maxpermsize similar to increments above (still fail)

Comment: More details on your tomcat installation, tomcat launcher (in Eclipse), java version and maybe even the webapp would be preferred. Are you using any particular frameworks? Are there any loops when loading the application?

Comment: Tomcat installation is all default settings from version 7.0.27

Comment: The WebApp is a modularized project (presentation-war , service-jar, domain-jar layers) with 1 parent pom used via maven to build all 3 projects. The WebApp is built around Spring and Hibernate.

Comment: The only plugins I'm using are: m2eclipse, and m2eclipse+extras (wtp)

Comment: Tomcat VM Args: -Dcatalina.base="C:\Apps\eclipse-indigo-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0" -Dcatalina.home="C:\Apps\apache-tomcat-7.0.27" -Dwtp.deploy="C:\Apps\eclipse-indigo-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\Apps\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\endorsed"

Comment: It might be that the OOME is happening in Eclipse, not Tomcat.  Maybe play with Eclipse memory settings?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these will help explain:

http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-oome-out-of-memory-error

http://baskarfelix.wordpress.com/2008/08/06/out-of-memory-errorjava-heap-space/

I'd also be curious to know if you have the same issue if you leave Eclipse out of the picture.  Create a WAR file, add it to the Tomcat /webapps directory, and start Tomcat using a command shell and the start script in the /bin directory.  If you still have a problem, I'd say you should look at how Tomcat and your JVM are configured.  If you don't, it tells me that Eclipse is the problem.

Comment: I just tried creating the WAR and deployed it to a standalone tomcat server and it works perfectly fine with zero errors. So this is definitely an Eclipse issue, but I can't seem to figure out what to update.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings look good to me. You could try the long way of profiling [1] tomcat to see what happens on startup, or the crude way of deleting your local server and runtime, to see if it helps with a fresh one. If that fails, re-download latest Eclipse Java EE edition, and set up from scratch.

While it's not the best solution (in case the problem resurfaces, you still have no proper solution), it is sometimes worth it if it takes too long otherwise.

[1] You could profile with JProfiler or YourKit Profiler. Both have trial versions. JVisualVM is also an alternative that comes with the JDK. However it may be an issue if Tomcat crashes immediately.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I actually tried out what you suggested and still have the same issue. But I did find the root cause of the issue during the process, which you can refer to answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your inputs. I was able to narrow it down to what was the root cause of the whole issue. I had an external api jar file in the src/main/resources/lib of my services layer and Eclipse seems to not like that for whatever reason. As soon as I moved that out of that location, it resolved the issue. Can anyone explain why this would potentially cause an issue? Just for learning purposes. Thanks!